# эмулятор использует не тот layout

Tags: android, genymotion, design

Эмулятор genymotion sony xperia tablet z берет layout файл из папки layout-large.
Как я понимаю, все планшеты по 10 дюймов должны использовать layout-xlarge.
Причем xperia tablet s использует layout-xlarge. Что может быть не так?

Comment: а вы уверены, что у вас эмулируется 10 дюймовый экран? Нужно вообще, больше информации, чтобы вам поочь

Comment: как проверить какого размера экран эмулируется в genymotion? внешне на экране монитора он стандартного размера, такого же, как и все 10дюймовые планшеты. какую информацию добавить? В пустом проекте есть папки layout-large и layout-xlarge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как я понимаю, все планшеты по 10 дюймов должны использовать layout-xlarge

Модификатор `xlarge` указывает на размер экрана в пикселях, а не в сантиментрах/дюймах. У экранов устройств с одинаковой диагональю бывает разная плотность пикселей (dpi) и, соответственно, разные размеры в пикселях

Comment: Исправил ответ.

Comment: И опять неправильно. Почитайте http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @metalurgus, ```xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp```. Что не так?

Comment: то, что `xlarge` указывает на размер экрана в `dp`, а не в пикселях, как вы написали. А `dp` является относительной единицей измерения длинны (физических размеров), так же, как и сантиметр, дюйм, метр, но имеет несколько плавающий размер.